# how to allow for Apache to read/write to user home directory?

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu

I want to allow for Apache to upload files to user home directory  `/homw/username/upload_files` which is outside the webserver root `/var/www/website/`

my apache server is currently running under user "www-data".
I changed the group owner of the target folder `/homw/username/upload_files` to `www-data` , and changed the permission to rwx

`drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 6 Dec  6 09:46 upload_files`

However, I am not able to figure out how to allow for apache to upload files to user's home directory.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/public_html.html has some information on how to set per-user directories. If you want a writeable directory, you'll need to make sure the directory itself has write/exec permissions, but read https://serverfault.com/questions/478321/apache-per-user-permissions first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest one of the following approaches and both working with me.

1- Change Ownership of full path `/home/username/upload_files`  to apache user `www-data` and give owner-write permission.
 `sudo chown -R www-data:www-data  /homw/username/upload_files`

please note that this will change owner of home directory including all entire folders to `www-data`

2- So, I prefer to move the `upload_files` to root directory and change the owner  to `www-data`

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data  /upload_files`